# Azure Function App in PowerShell generating host threshold exceeded errors

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We just started getting this error yesterday but haven't changed anything in our app.  Any ideas?  If we restart the function app, it will run for a short time and then start giving us this error again.  The function app is in PowerShell.

```
Host Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections]
```

Comment: Some code snippet could help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about code snippet.  I was able to repo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the above change that caused this but it is a coding issue on my side that is now being handled correctly by Azure Functions.  I created this small repo and after I commented out the close, I received the error.  My real code is more complex but clearly somewhere I'm not closing it out.

```
$Ports = @(21,22,23,53,69,71,80,98,110,139,111,389,443,445,1080,1433,2001,2049,3001,3128,5222,6667,6868,7777,7878,8080,1521,3306,3389,5801,5900,5555,5901)

for($i = 1; $i -le $ports.Count;$i++) {
            $port = $Ports[($i-1)]
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect("123.123.123.123",$port,$null,$null)
#$client.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was recently added in the runtime to track running out of available connections on the VM

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/2063

It should point to you running out of available connections. It could be wrong or correct, but I can't tell without looking at your functions themselves.

If you would like to discuss it, then you probably should use the repo above